# How to remove this cronjob in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm running a webserver with PLESK and installed an extension 'kernel care' which I later on deleted. However, it installed a cronjob which sends me a mail every 4 hours:

```
Cron <root@server> /usr/bin/kcarectl --auto-update
Unknown Kernel (Ubuntu 3.13.0-042stab123.9)
```

I ssh into the server and run crontab -l as root **but don't see the specific cronjob**. However, in /etc/cron.d there is a file kcare-cron and if I cat this file it shows

```
16 */4  * * * root /usr/bin/kcarectl --auto-update
```

So thats the one I want to delete. Can I just delete the file kcare-cron?

Answer (score 10):

1- Open terminal & type

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Now either remove cron command or marked '#' at start of command.
Now save file (ctrl + O, & ctrl +X) & exit.

2- Do second option

```
sudo crontab -r
```

Note: This will remove all cron job.

Comment: The line is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Type below command in terminal:

```
contab -e
```

then comment the line with `#` at the start of line as below:

```
#16 */4  * * * root /usr/bin/kcarectl --auto-update
```

Or if you want to delete you can delete the line.

On saving the file it will automatically use changes in crontab.

Comment: But the line is not there.

Comment: If you want to edit crontab for other user you can try `sudo crontab -e -u username` check here https://serverfault.com/questions/185703/how-do-i-edit-the-crontab-of-another-user-on-my-linux-server

Comment: From above line in crontab.d it looks like the user is root right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Command Line and type "crontab -e".
2. it will open the cron file to add the cronjobs.
3. Now, scroll at the bottom or last line to this file and add the line or cron job to this file using cron job format.
4. If you want to delete or remove the cron then simple add the "#" at the start of a line or remove that whole line.
5. Save the file and cron is added cron job list

Comment: But the line is not there. Like I said its also not visible in crontab -l

Comment: Are you using ubuntu system, right?

If Yes then run the step 1 and add the line which you want to run

Comment: I don't want to add a job, I want to delete one which is sending me mails. However, this specific job is not in the crontab.

Comment: Oh Okay so, that is on /etc/cron.d/ file, Right?

if Yes then open that file and if you found the line there?

Comment: Yes, like I said in my original post, when I cat the file kcare-cron in the cron.d directory I see.

    16 */4  * * * root /usr/bin/kcarectl --auto-update

Comment: Do you know where you have added the cronjob?

Comment: This is probably done by the extension when I installed it in Plesk

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are sent by cron job configured in one of the following files `/etc/cron.d/kcare-cron.rpmsave` or `/etc/cron.d/kcare-cron`. Remove these files:

```
rm -f /etc/cron.d/kcare-cron.rpmsave
rm -f /etc/cron.d/kcare-cron
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check file

```
/etc/cron.allow
```

and see if accounts other than root exist, if there is then su to those accounts and try all the suggested actions above.